# InDesign script to print .indd into .pdf

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, indesign-scripting

As the title says we were discussing scripting processes and we noticed this has not been asked nor do I know if it can be done.  Can you create an InDesign script that will take all `.indd` files and print/export them to `.pdf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 44 of the cs5 indesign scripting guide has code samples for exporting PDF files. One only need provide code to open and close the required files. The easy way is to pipe or provide a file list, the less easy way is to enumerate the indd files (or shortcuts to randomly scattered files) in a folder and then open and export each in turn.

```
var myPDFExportPreset = app.pdfExportPresets.item("prepress");
app.activeDocument.exportFile(ExportFormat.pdfType, File("/c/myTestDocument.pdf"),
false, myPDFExportPreset);
```